# Do dog whistles work for barking?

Tags: dogs, large-dogs

Lately we’ve had several large dogs bark at all ours of the night, for several minutes at a time.

We’ve talked to the owners, and they have made an effort to control their pets, but it hasn’t stopped the dogs from barking alot.

I’m thinking of buying one of those dog whistles so that they stop barking.

Do these dog whistles work?

Answer (score 1):

The barks of the dog are pretty much low frequency, so they can travel easily through the walls. The larger the dog, the lower the frequencies.

However, the dog-whistles generate ultrasounds, which are very unlikely to travel through the same walls. While you can still give it a try (especially if you find the whistle at a convenient price), it might not do too much good.

---

To understand better: when some neighbors listen to music, you hear very well the beats (low frequencies), but you might not make much out of the rest of the song (higher frequencies).

Answer (score 0):

The small silent whistles you probably mean with "dog whistles" probably won't work. They come in different frequencies and - since they are intended for training instead of dog repelling - the frequecies won't stop the dogs from barking.

What you want is something that actually causes pain to punish the dogs for barking. There are special dog repellant whistles or devices that have a frequency that's painful for dogs and cats to hear. If you really want to stop the barking, you have to use one of those.

And it's absolutely important that you keep this in mind: **whenever you activate such a device, you hurt every dog and cat around you.** If misused, they can cause hearing loss (which of cause makes them ineffective) and the dogs may start hating you personally when they see you using such a repellant (because they learn that you cause them pain).